# Convert a python numpy array to c++ stl vector

Tags: c++, python, arrays, vector, numpy

I'm looking for a way to read in c++ a text file containing numpy arrays and put the data into `vector< vector< ... > >` , can anyone help me out please ?

Thanks a lot.
Archy

**EDIT:** format of the text file

```
[[[ 0 1] [ 2 3] [ 4 5] [ 6 7] [ 8 9]] [[10 11] [12 13] [14 15] [16 17] [18 19]] [[20 21] [22 23] [24 25] [26 27] [28 29]] [[30 31] [32 33] [34 35] [36 37] [38 39]]]
```

Perhaps more readably:

```
[
    [
        [ 0 1] [ 2 3] [ 4 5] [ 6 7] [ 8 9]
    ]
    [
        [10 11] [12 13] [14 15] [16 17] [18 19]
    ]
    [
        [20 21] [22 23] [24 25] [26 27] [28 29]
    ]
    [
        [30 31] [32 33] [34 35] [36 37] [38 39]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the sort of data you need to read? How is it formatted?

Comment: of couse, this something like 

[[[ 0  1]
  [ 2  3]
  [ 4  5]
  [ 6  7]
  [ 8  9]]

 [[10 11]
  [12 13]
  [14 15]
  [16 17]
  [18 19]]

 [[20 21]
  [22 23]
  [24 25]
  [26 27]
  [28 29]]

 [[30 31]
  [32 33]
  [34 35]
  [36 37]
  [38 39]]]

(sorry for the format, how can beautify it ?)

Comment: You can use "`" around your text in the comments.

Comment: Is the level of nesting (3) in your example constant ? And more generally, is the format constant, or do you have a way to get the various dimensions somewhere ?

Comment: well, there are 3 level arrays in the text file, and the first dimension is variant whereas the other two dimensions are fixed.
As an example, we can find :
‘(12, 36, 36)
(100, 36, 36)
(83, 36, 36)
....‘

Answer (score 0):

```
float val;
::std::vector<float> vals;
ifstream stream("c:/file.txt");
while(stream >> val) {
   vals.push_back(val);
}
```

Comment: I think the real problem here is that `@Archy` as an array of arrays of arrays, so it's a bit more difficult.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your efforts :)

Comment: Well, in the numpy documentation, they say there is a C-API ... great :)

But, I new in C++, can anyone tell me how to include the API inside the C++ code ? 

(I didn't find any C library to download, so I concluded that it is implicitely installed with Numpy... ?)

Answer (score 0):

It's going to depend on your level of expertise.

If you are experienced, I would suggest something like [Boost.Spirit.Qi](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html), which is a true parser library. However it might take some time to get used to.

Otherwise it depends on what information you have at your disposal... I'll edit my answer when you provide us with more details since it's hairy enough to potentially get quite complicated :)